# EDT in Java, how does it work, does it behave like normal thread (single or mutli)?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, listener, event-dispatch-thread

this is a beginner question:
I am working on a small chat program that use TCP to deliver messages, and I have a simple GUI to display it, I have finished the program, but the EDT has confused me a lot...

1. does EDT behave like it "extends Thread"? I imagine it is a single thread since I will need worker thread to process the heavy logic, but apparently I can not do Thread.sleep/yield (I have a **while loop** that constantly reading message from the outputstream and append to the jTextArea, running in **main Thread**, I tried to terminate the **while loop** by set a false flag and then yield to **main Thread**, did not work.)
2. I am not so sure about how listener works, if I have to write it...I will probably start a thread for each listener, as soon as I hear something I will process it...but this is definitely wrong because it will make EDT a **multithread** ( a lot of ears ) but **singlethread** during the process ( only 1 brain )

This must be me lacking knowledge!! because in my head I just can not figure out how to **fire an event**... you pressed a button and java suddenly knows? I must missed something.

My first time post a question, hope it is clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Event Dispatching Thread is a `Thread` like any other `Thread` in Java.

It is responsible for dispatching all events and repaint requests (and few other things, like running synchronized `Runnable`).  Any action you take that blocks the EDT will stop it from processing these events, making it look like your application has hung ... because basically it has.

All interactions with any UI component MUST be executed within the context of the EDT.  That means you should never try and create or update any UI component from any `Thread` other then the EDT.

If you need to do any actions that are blocking or time consuming, you should use another thread.  `SwingWorker` is an excellent place to start.

Adding listeners to component will not create more threads.  The EDT will post event notifications back to the listeners (this is an incredibly shortened explanation, but the concept is sound), this is one of the reasons why you should never block the EDT.

How events are raised depends on the component.  Mouse and keyboard events for example, will be posted to the Event Queue by a native portion of code dependent on the OS/implementation (as I understand it, coming from the `ToolKit`, but I could be wrong).

`actionPerformed` events raised by `JButtons` may be executed directly against the listener (not dispatched via the Event Queue), but within the EDT.  This are raised by any number of events, but typically caused by mouse clicks and special key events.  The `JButton` is notified of these because it registers itself with the Event Queue.

While getting an understanding of the workings is a good goal, you need to ask yourself, does it matter (in the short term)?  Do you know how electricity gets from the light switch to the light?  Or do you only care that it does?

Understand the rules required to use it (don't stick sharp objects into the power points) and let the understanding come as you become more confident.